# Python sending packets with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, packet

I'm trying to send TCP packets with Python. It works perfectly fine if I send it to mysel f(I use Wireshark to see if was succesful), but if I send it from a device in another network to me it wont work. (I compiled it to exe).

```py
try:
    Count = 1
    seconds=600
    IPdst = ip
    t_end = time.time() + seconds
    while time.time() < t_end:
        Count += 1
        for x in range(1):
            one=(random.randint(1,255))
        for x in range(1):
            two=(random.randint(1,255))
        for x in range(1):
            three=(random.randint(1,255))
        for x in range(1):
            four=(random.randint(1,255))
        dot = "."
        one=str(one)
        two=str(two)
        three=str(three)
        four=str(four)

        RndIP=(one+dot+two+dot+three+dot+four)

        A = RndIP
        B = IPdst
        C = RandShort()
        D = 80
        payload = "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "


        spoofed_packet = IP(src=A, dst=B) / TCP(sport=C, dport=D) / Raw(load = payload)
        send(spoofed_packet,inter = .0, verbose = False)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, but why are you using `for` loops there? And also, I recommend this a lot, but you should always specify the `iface` argument when using `send` and similar functions. You don't want Scapy guessing which interface to use.

Comment: when you say: "another Network", what do you mean? also having a random src IP might be the cause of you problem, as you most likely end up with an IP not in you subnerwork